# Any way to represent the file-memory relation in a Portable Executable (PE) file?

Tags: tools, pe

I am looking for a way to automatically represent the relation between the content of a PE file and how it would be loaded in memory - either an IDA plugin, a combination of pefile script+R/SVG...

Something that could look like this (hand drawn):

[image]

(Not necessarily something that already supports PE, but that could be extended freely to support PE)

Comment: How did you draw this by hand ?

Comment: In Inkscape (FYI [here](http://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE101?show=content) is the file)

Comment: Yes, nice illustration!

Answer (score 1):

TeX ([TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/)) could be used for it. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102590/why-draw-diagrams-using-latex-when-there-are-open-source-tools-like-openoffice) for some discussion and examples.

Comment: Try to add a short explanation or description for the application here itself.

Answer (score 1):

You've seen [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php), right? It is a free PE Editor/viewer by Daniel Pistelli (the author of the IDA 6.x Qt GUI) that breaks out a PE file by field. This is not a vector graphic display like you are asking for, but it may serve the same need.

Comment: I know and use regularly CFF Explorer and its sequel, Cerbero Profiler, but they don't have any graphical representation for section mappings.

Comment: My bad. In my defense, I did state that as a disclaimer in my answer.

Comment: @dingo_kinznerhook Don't feel bad, there is nothing wrong with contributing an answer. That's why I don't like the fact that answers can be downvoted negative. I makes sense to vote them down to 0, but -1 is just an insult and discourages contribution :o.